# How do I change the size the image being displayed "dynamically" in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a custom Wordpress Site and I need to be able to output the image being assigned to the post as the "Featured Image" So, here is my PHP code

```
$theimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID(), array( 160,260 ), false, '' ), 'product-image2');    
$product_shortcode .= '<li>';
$product_shortcode .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h4>'. get_the_title().'</h4>';
$product_shortcode .= '<img src="'.$theimage[0].'" alt="" /> ';
$product_shortcode .= '</a>';
$product_shortcode .= '</li>';
```

And now here is my problem
[image]
The image is being displayed in (160 x 140) As you can see. I need the image to be displayed wholly. When I inspected it the image src in output was ../~image-path/feed160x140.png. Which is the thumbnail size generated by wordpress. If it displayed the normal ../~image-path/feed.png I would be fine.

In my code, and according to the [Wordpress Reference Website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) the array(160X260) should display it in those dimensions. Not happening for me.

I need help from the WP Gurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I hope this is working for you.

```
$theimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'full');    
$product_shortcode .= '<li>';
$product_shortcode .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h4>'. get_the_title().'</h4>';
$product_shortcode .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$theimage[0].'" alt="" /> ';
$product_shortcode .= '</a>';

$product_shortcode .= '</li>';
```

Used `img-responsive` this class directly if you used bootstrap 3 other wise write css like.

```
.img-responsive{
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: VOILA!!!!!!  DONE! Thanks, I had to do some minor mods to the css class, but the PHP worked beautifully! +1 and answer checked

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my first answer. I missed something very obvious.

You are using [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) which only take the post ID as a parameter,  yet you are passing parameters for [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail). You are also passing a parameter that does not exist to to `get_the_post_thumbnail`.

Instead of using

```
get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID(), array( 160,260 ), false, '' )
```

You should use

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(160,260) );
```

Comment: This took the image out completely. :(

Comment: I +1 your efforts anyway. I think your logic makes sense, but probably because of other factors in my code, your logic was probably being nulled. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just glad I could be of some help. Thanks